# D3 touch screen vs mouse usage issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hover, touch, collision

We have implemented the org chart from http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 and we are experiencing issues with the collision of nodes for dragging and dropping on a touch screen. The issue exists in the original example noted here as well.

Using touchstart, touchmove, touchend events are not helping as the problem is tied to recognizing the collision on hover.

Any help or thoughts are much appreciated!!

Comment: Could you tell us what these issues are?

Comment: On touching of a node it will try to pan but the node will stay in its relative position whereas the panning should stop and the node continue to move. (this was solved with a boolean). Once the movement of a node is available it does not connect to the other nodes in the same manner as a mouse this is likely due to a mouseover event not having a mirror in touch events. beyond this the way we have drawn the svg it is only a portion of the page, with a side div that houses further information. on usage of the pan, zoom, or drag functions, the scroll in the other div no longer works on touch.

Comment: Hmm, I don't immediately see anything that would be specific to mouse events in the dragging.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks so much for taking a look! It is so weird that is works fine on a desktop but the touch screen is messing it up. We are working on killing the drag and drop at this point and going with a single touch at this point. I'll post up what we do for anyone who might face a similar issue.

Comment: Facing the same problem "mouseover" will not fire when you are swiping you finger onto an element, did you manage to fix the drag and drop or changed the way i works as you posted in you last comment?